# ember route name taking care of the path

Tags: ember.js

I need to write a `<link rel="canonical" href="www.website.com/CURRENT_PATH"/>`. I'm getting half way with the code below, but I'm missing the translation that is in the router. How can the CURRENT_PATH reflect the url?

Current code in the ApplicationController:

```
  setCanonicalURL: function() {
    'use strict';

    $('head link[rel="canonical"]').attr("href", "http://website.com/" + this.get('currentRouteName'));
  }.observes('currentRouteName'),
```

This gives me `http://website.com/search.index` while I want it to be `http://website.com/products/index`

My router contains:

```
  this.resource('search', { path: '/products'} , function(){
    this.route('index');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elegant and simple in the end:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  setCanonicalURL: function() {
    'use strict';

    $('head link[rel="canonical"]').attr("href", "http://website.com" + this.get('target.url'));
  }.observes('target.url')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
this.get('currentPath').replace(/\./g,'/');
```

instead of:

```
this.get('currentRouteName');
```

Comment: most important here is the "rename" that happens with the path in the router. Both currentPath and currentRoute return search.index